# FInd and replace in file

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a very simple search and replace php script but it doesn't work. Can you please advice me on what am I doing wrong here ?

```
if(isset($_GET['fnr'])) {
    $find = $_GET['find'];
    $replace = $_GET['replace'];

    $path_to_file = 'index.php';
    $file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
    $file_contents = str_replace("$find","$replace",$file_contents);
    file_put_contents($path_to_file,$file_contents);
}
```

Comment: What's the issue? _It doesn't work_ isn't enough.

Comment: Nope it doesn't work. Don't know why .

Comment: ... Have you tried debugging your code? Is `$_GET['find']` not empty? You have reading and writing permissions on `index.php`? Is `$file_contents` modified after `str_replace`? [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: remove `"` from `$file_contents = str_replace("$find","$replace",$file_contents);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `"` from `$file_contents = str_replace("$find","$replace",$file_contents);`

**textfile.php**

> my name Frayne, My name also konok

**PHP**

```
  $find = "My name";
  $replace = "name";

  $path_to_file = 'textfile.php';
  $file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
  $file_contents = str_replace($find,$replace, $file_contents);
  file_put_contents($path_to_file,$file_contents);
```

**Output:**

> my name Frayne, name also konok

The output string remove the `My` from the file.

Comment: You can say it's useless to use such a construct `"$string"`, but that can't be the problem. `str_replace` accepts `strings` as params and afaik `"$string"` is the same string as `$string`.

Comment: Right i have to say `use " in a string is useless`, As i do the example, it works perfectly.